# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'win64': Native library (win32-x86-64/win64.dll) not found in resource path

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, jna, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am getting below Exception while accessing Windows 7 Native library using jna-4.4.0.jar

After adding `-Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true` parameter, I got below output with UnsatisfiedLinkError.

```
Trying (via loadLibrary) jnidispatch
Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Found library resource at jar:file:/C:/Users/vishwajit/workspace/Practice/lib/jna-4.4.0.jar!/com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Trying C:\Temp\jna--1067518124\jna4907966697518063795.dll
Found jnidispatch at C:\Temp\jna--1067518124\jna4907966697518063795.dll
Looking for library 'win64'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying win64.dll
Adding system paths: []
Trying win64.dll
Looking for lib- prefix
Trying libwin64.dll
Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 for win64
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'win64': Native library (win32-x86-64/win64.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/C:/Users/vishwajit/workspace/Practice/bin/, file:/C:/Users/vishwajit/workspace/Practice/lib/gson-2.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/vishwajit/workspace/Practice/lib/jna-platform-4.4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/vishwajit/workspace/Practice/lib/jna-4.4.0.jar])
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:303)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:427)
        at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:179)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:569)
        at download.wallpaper.WallpaperDownloader$User32.<clinit>(WallpaperDownloader.java:47)
        at download.wallpaper.WallpaperDownloader.main(WallpaperDownloader.java:43)
```

And, I am trying to load windows library by using below code to set wallpaper.

```
public static interface User32 extends Library{
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("win64", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    boolean SystemParametersInfo(int one, int two, String s, int three);
}
```

Now, I am unable to find a library path of win32-x86-64/win64.dll. Where it is located and whats a path?

Comment: Show which library you're trying to load and how.

Comment: Run with `-Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true` to get more information about where JNA is searching and what it finds.

Comment: So "win64" is the DLL name you give yourself. If you want to load user32, you should put in "user32". As in https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/32ea99a681560f160d0dbdda757f7f447b81d794/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.java

Comment: @user2543253, Its done already by changing it to "user32", thanks!